# PDF export has inaccurate dimensions

Tags: bugs, export, pdf-format, scaling

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and persisting through 13.0.0** [CASE:4895073]

---

The following code produces a 10x10 grid of numbers, each in a 20x6 mm cell.

```
mm = 72/25.4;
{bx, by} = {20 mm, 6 mm};

label[num_] := Graphics[
  Text[IntegerString[num, 10, 5], {10 mm, 3 mm}],
  ImageSize -> {bx, by}, PlotRange -> {{0, bx}, {0, by}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]

labels = label /@ Range[100];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[labels, 10], Spacings -> 0]

Export["number.pdf", %]
```

When exporting to PDF, irrespective of the number of cells (**even for a single cell without `GraphicsGrid`**), the PDF dimensions are not exact.

The exact dimensions should be 10x20 mm wide and 10x6 mm long, i.e. **200 x 60 mm**.

However, the actual output has dimensions of **204.3 x 64.6 mm**.

**How to resolve this ?**
Mathematica version is 11.2 running on Win 10 x64.

Of course, I could just add an approximate factor of ~0.979 in the `mm` definition, but that way it won't be really exact and will look ugly when merged with other graphics (in another program).

Comment: You have luck setting `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]`.

Comment: That should be might have luck.  In any case see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/137746#137746

Comment: @chuy Thank you for mentioning this! Despite the fact that I myself am the author of that answer, this important point completely slipped my mind...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, as [chuy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/237/chuy) correctly points out in the comments, you should set `PrintingStyleEnvironment` to `"Working"` in order to avoid magnification problems discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137746/280):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

Then, I suggest to use `Grid` instead of `GraphicsGrid` (the value `-.11` is found by trial and error):

```
Grid[Partition[labels, 10], Spacings -> {0, -.11}]
Export["number.pdf", %] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

The above screenshot is of the PDF file exported with *Mathematica* 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64.

But with *Mathematica* 12.3.1 and 8.0.4 I get a PDF image of size 201 x 60 mm. This is version-dependent since even the *actual* meaning of `ImageSize` changed significantly in the latest versions, apart from updated PDF exporter.

If you need exact control over the size of the final image, the best what you can do is to make a `Graphics` object with your contents by using low-level functions like `Inset` and `Text`, and not relying on any high-level functionality.

An example:

```
mm = 72/25.4;

coords = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {y, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}], 1];

labels = IntegerString[Range[100], 10, 5];

imageSize = {200 mm, 60 mm};
gr = Graphics[MapThread[Text, {labels, coords}], 
   PlotRange -> {{.5, 10.5}, {.5, 10.5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> imageSize, AspectRatio -> 1/Divide @@ imageSize];

Export["number.pdf", gr] // SystemOpen
```

This should give the exact size of the exported PDF, but even with version 13.0.0 it does not:

[image: screenshot]

... but version 8.0.4 exports a PDF with exact image size:

[image: screenshot]

Hence we have a regression in the PDF exporter in the latest *Mathematica* versions. Reported to the support as [CASE:4895073].

**Update.** I just received a response from the support. Here is an excerpt:

> Thank you for taking the time to send your report.
>
> It does appear that Export[] is not preserving the specified image
> size with the PDF files it generates. <...>
>
> This issue appears to have started in Mathematica 12.1, so any earlier
> versions should not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: My output using `Grid` is 144.6 x 58.6 mm only. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @tobalt Added some thoughts.

Comment: So you suggest making a single Graphics with multiple `Text` directives, each placed at the corresponding position. Actually I doubt this would work. As I mentioned in my question, even for a single `Text` without `GraphicsGrid`, it didn't work. Thanks for your help, but I think I am gonna piece it together with Python, where at least the PDF export is exact.

Comment: @tobalt Yes, producing pixel-perfect graphics with *Mathematica* is always a challenge, and everything can break in an unexpected way. If you will make your Python solution work through *Mathematica*, please share it.

Comment: It doesn't use Mathematica, but I have added it below anyway, in case anyone would be interested.

Comment: @tobalt Updated the answer with a response from the support confirming the bug.

Comment: Thanks. But as I wrote above, v 11.2 also doesn't get it right with neither Grid nor GraphicsGrid. So there seems to be more buggy than only the PDF exporter. ‍♂️

Comment: @tobalt I'm sorry, but I completely forgot that in my *Mathematica* 13.0.0 `PrintingStyleEnvironment` was set to `"Working"` permanently, but in versions 12.3.1 and 8.0.4 it wasn't. This made my answer inconsistent. Now I've rewritten it to make all the results consistent with recommended setting `PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"`.

Comment: I've inserted the `SetOptions`, but still no luck. Yes, `Grid` export is now closer to the intended size, but not exact. (201.1 x 80.8) instead of (200 x 60). Also you mention that you found the spacing of -.11 by trial and error. Such finetuned and *unexplained* value is not really conducive to building trust in an accurately scaled PDF export method. So I still see no resolution here (but thank you very much for your effort and for escalating this). Btw the Inset+Text method is also not exact, it exports the same size here as in your version 13 test.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, here is a workaround using `matplotlib` of Python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mm = 1 / 25.4

#Array size
nx = 10
ny = 40
#Cell size
cx = 20*mm
cy = 6*mm

#relative position (left-center justified) of text in cell
npx = 0.25
npy = 0.7

plt.figure(figsize=(cx*nx, cy*ny))

for x in (np.arange(nx)+1):
    for y in (np.arange(ny)+1):
        plt.figtext( (npx+x-1)/nx, (npy+y-1)/ny, f'{x+nx*(y-1):06.0f}', horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', size=72*3*mm, fontfamily='consolas', weight='bold')

plt.savefig("numbers-py.pdf")
```

[image]